# How to incorporate links inside a hamburger menu?

Tags: html, css, navbar, hamburger-menu

I am having a hard time on how to re-arrange my HTML/CSS code in order to move a few links inside of a hamburger nav menu.

I would like to have 'home' always visible but then, I would like the other linked pages to fall inside the hamburger menu, only visible when clicking the menu...

I would like the following to be inside the hamburger menu:

About
Contact 
Portfolio ,etc.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

```css
    * {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    body {
        background-color: #f3f3f3;
    }
    
    header {
       background-color: #fff; 
       width: 100%;
       height: 100px;
       display: table-cell;
    }
    
    .header-logo img {
        height:100px;
        padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
        float: left;
    }
    
    header nav ul {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: fit-content;
        padding-top: 30px;
    }
    
    header nav ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0 5px;
    }
    
    header nav ul li a {
        font-family:'Sorts Mill Goudy', serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #111;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    .sub {
        display: none;
        background-color: rgb(70, 149, 223);
        margin-left: 5%;
        height: auto;
    }
    
    /* HAMBURGER MENU */
    .nav div {
        height: 4px;
        background-color: rgb(20, 15, 15);
        margin:  5px 0;
        border-radius: 25px;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .nav {
        width: 30;
        display: block;
        float: right;
        margin: 1em 0 0 1em;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }
    
    .one {
        width: 30px;
    } 
    
    .two {
        width: 20px;
    } 
    
    .three {
        width: 25px;
    } 
    
    .nav:hover div{
        width: 30px;
    }
    
    
    
    
    ul li a:hover {
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    }
```

```html
<header>
<div class="header-logo">
<a href="index.html"> <img src="img/Milestonehackers.jpg" alt="Milestonehackers logo"></a>
</div>
            <nav>
                <ul> <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li></ul>
            <ul>
              <a href="#" class="nav">
                    <div class="one"></div>
                    <div class="two"></div>
                    <div class="three"></div>        
             
                <li><a href="podcasts.html">Podcast</a></li>
                <li><a href="newsletter.html">Newsletter</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    
                <div class="sub">
                <li><a href="subscribe.html">Subscribe</a></li>
                </div>
                </a>  
            </ul> 
            </nav>
        </header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [toggle](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp). For this you need to use javascript or [jquery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/) (a simplified javascript "version"). To easy explain this, put for example a  parent div for the child elements you want to toggle. Then in your css display this parent div none. Then you use jquery to be able to tell what you want to be clickable and then later what you want to toggle.

```js
//Script.js
$(document).ready(function(){ //Use ready to make a function available after the document is loaded
$(".nav").click(function(){
 $("#hamburger").toggle(250);
});
});
```

```css
 /* Style.css */
* {
    text-decoration: none;
}

body {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

header {
   background-color: #fff; 
   width: 100%;
   height: 100px;
   display: table-cell;
}

.header-logo img {
    height:100px;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
    float: left;
}

header nav ul {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: fit-content;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

header nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 5px;
}

header nav ul li a {
    font-family:'Sorts Mill Goudy', serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #111;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.sub {
    display: none;
    background-color: rgb(70, 149, 223);
    margin-left: 5%;
    height: auto;
}

/* HAMBURGER MENU */
.nav div {
    height: 4px;
    background-color: rgb(20, 15, 15);
    margin:  5px 0;
    border-radius: 25px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.nav {
    width: 30;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin: 1em 0 0 1em;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.one {
    width: 30px;
} 

.two {
    width: 20px;
} 

.three {
    width: 25px;
} 

.nav:hover div{
    width: 30px;
}

#hamburger{
  display:none;
}



ul li a:hover {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "script.js">
 
</head>
<header>
        <div class="header-logo">
        <a href="index.html"> <img src="https://milestonehackers.com/img/Milestonehackers.jpg" alt="Milestonehackers logo"></a>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul> <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li></ul>
        <ul>
          <a href="#" class="nav">
                <div class="one"></div>
                <div class="two"></div>
                <div class="three"></div>        
<div id = "hamburger">

            <li><a href="podcasts.html">Podcast</a></li>
            <li><a href="newsletter.html">Newsletter</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>

</div>
            <div class="sub">
            <li><a href="subscribe.html">Subscribe</a></li>
            </div>
            </a>  
        </ul> 
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Edit: I added the src to the new script.js file which should contain your click function:)

Comment: note: dont forget to add <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script> in your head to be able to use jquery

Comment: Hi @Unknown Potato, I have added the script as indicated but the js jquery code isn't functioning. Gives me 3 errors (I'm totally new to this so I'm sure its something on my end). at-rule or selector expected css(css-ruleorselectorexpected), (css-lcurlyexpected), and the first one again. Any idea how to correct this?

Comment: did you add <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>  in your head?

Comment: I put the script inside the index.html, the head section. The code snippet I put inside style.css file... I have a feeling I did that wrong lol

Comment: i'l edit my answer so it's easier to understand then, the jquery code can't be inside the style.css you need a new file that ends with .js   ex script.js

Answer (score 1):

Don't think you could achieve what you want only using CSS, maybe with a lot of CSS "hacks". I'd suggest adding some javascript to show on click.

I'd recommend checking this page https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_mobile_navbar.asp since they have an example just like the one you trying to achieve.